# Bind table row's class to checkbox checked state

Tags: angular

I created a table where the first column contains a checkbox that is used to select its parent row. I'm trying to style the table so that the whole row has a blue background when selected.

component typescript:

```
public items = [{ name: 'row 1' }, { name: 'row 2' }, { name: 'etc' }];
```

component template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th><!-- selector column --></th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items" [ngClass]="{ selected: selector.checked }">
      <td><input #selector type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

component stylesheet:

```
tr.selected {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Binding [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to the checked state of the checkbox in each row appears to work at least partially. When a box is [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-checked), the `selected` class is added to the row **but** only after a very noticeable delay.

I believe that the class is not added until after change detection runs and it appears that the act of checking the box does not trigger change detection.

Am I doing something wrong? My component uses the default change detection strategy.

Angular 4.1.3

Here is a Plunkr demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/Tj6IU5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <tr [ngClass]="{ selected: selector.checked }">
    <td><input #selector type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

or

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" [ngClass]="{ selected: inputs[i] }">
  <td><input type="checkbox" (change)="inputs[i] = $event.target.value"></td>
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

```
...
this.items = ...;
this.inputs = new Array(this.items.length);
this.inputs.fill(false);
```

Comment: I assumed you do, because of `#selector` and the element itself not having an event binding (like demonstrated in my answer). There are essential parts missing in the code in your question, this is why I made assumptions.

Comment: Oh ok. No, all my code is in the markup. I don't use an event handler. Instead, I was trying to add a one-way binding from `ngClass` to the `checked` property of the checkbox input element. The `checked` property is a native HTML thing, not an Angular thing. That's why I think the binding doesn't work properly.

Comment: AFAIR a parent element can't reference a template variable of a child. You can try my above example with `<ng-container>` but I guess it won't work (same as your own code). Alternatively, use an array to store the states of the checkboxes and bind to this instead.

Comment: The binding does work the way I have it, but I have to force change detection. See my test case: https://plnkr.co/edit/Tj6IU5?p=preview

Comment: I see. I'm pretty sure `(click)="true"` would do the same.

Comment: As in on the checkbox or on the button? I'm trying to get rid of the button. Maybe I should just do `(change)="app.tick()"` on the checkbox...

Comment: Sorry, again, not fully awake yet it seems. I meant `(change)="true"`. Every event binding causes change detection when an event happens. `app.tick()` is kinda a sledgehammer because it runs change detection for the whole application. If you are using `OnPush`, inject `public cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef` and use `(change)="cdRef.markForCheck()"`, this only causes change detection for the current component.